# "Named colors do not work prior to iOS 11.0" error referring to a storyboard

Tags: ios, interface-builder

While developing an iOS application for targets below iOS 11, I accidentally left a named color in one of my storyboards. However, the error I got only shows the name of the storyboard and not the exact view that is causing the issue:

[image: Error, text transcription: see below]

> Named colors do not work prior to iOS 11.0
>   Main.storyboard

How can I find the exact views that have a named color as a property and replace those with a non-named color?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get the exact floating point values of your named colours, and then do a find / replace so that you can do a quick "replace all" instead of editing each individual colour. Just search for "namedColor" in your storyboard and you will find the colorus as they would appear normally eg.

```
<namedColor name="Grey Background">
     <color red="0.92941176470588238" green="0.93333333333333335" blue="0.94117647058823528" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
</namedColor>
```

Then do a Find/Replace with the search term:

```
name="Grey Background"/>
```

And copy-paste the following into the "With" section of the Find / Replace:

```
red="0.92941176470588238" green="0.93333333333333335" blue="0.94117647058823528" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
```

Then hit "replace all". Don't forget to include the "/>" at the end of both the search term and the replacement text as this will ensure the name is not replaced in the "namedColor" section at the bottom of the storyboard document.

This should then replace all colours in your storyboard that match the exact name. Now just right-click the storyboard and open in interface builder again and the file will recompile and all colours should still look the same.

Things to note:

1. Always make sure you either commit then push to your repository or at least make a backup copy of your storyboard file before you make any changes to it's source.
2. Do this same process for all .xib files that may contain the named colours too otherwise your project wont compile.
3. You can use this same process if you ever have to change a colour project-wide without having to change it for each individual view. Just do a find / replace for the RGB values you pasted above and this will allow you to do a "replace all" for that colour in the future.

Answer (score 38):

1. Open the storyboard as Source Code. (**right click on the storyboard file inside the Project navigator/Open As/Source Code**)

   [image: Open As/Source Code]
2. Navigate to **Find/Find and Replace...** (or press <kbd>⌥⌘F</kbd>).
3. Open the dropdown list on the right side and select **Regular Expression**.

   [image: the button that toggles the dropdown on the right side of the Find view]

   [image: Regular Expression selected from the dropdown]
4. For the search term, enter the following regex:

   ```
   color key=(.*) name=.*
   ```

   For the replacement, enter this:

   ```
   color key=$1 red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
   ```

   This regular expression essentially **captures the key** of the `color` property with `(.*)` and inserts it again with `$1`.

   Keep in mind that this example **replaces the color to white**. Change the color by providing a different RGB value.
5. Switch back to Interface Builder by navigating to **Open As/Interface Builder - Storyboard** in the right click menu that was mentioned in the first step.

Comment: Easier to change expand all your views (start at the top and hit right arrow, down arrow, right arrow, down arrow) and then look for the background color, or color that has a name in the description (named color). Then click on the dropdown and hit "Other..." and tap on the rounded color preview square. It will then replace your named color with the same color. I find it strange that Apple doesn't support named colors in IB in iOS versions prior to 11. There's no reason why it couldn't work.

Comment: @JorisWeimar Yes, that can be a valid method as well. I'd suggest writing a separate answer about it.

Comment: I replaced the key=$1 to key="1" and worked!! TY

color key="1" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>

Answer (score 14):

For cordova projects, I fixed updating the config.xml
from

```
<preference name="deployment-target"            value="10" />
```

to

```
<preference name="deployment-target"            value="12" />
```

Comment: Does this mean the app will no longer be supported on iOS 10 ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply set the minimum Deployment Target to 11.0 or greater both in Target's and Project's Build Settings. It will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the exact views that have a named color as a property to replace with a non-named color by clicking on the error with the component view opened, this will select automatically the view.

[image: meuTutorial]

Answer (score 0):

This only valid if you are in target build is 11. In my case even I target 11 this not reflected.Identified the issue. This might not the answer for late visiter just have some Idea.

Go to storyboard from xcode, then 'File inspector' in property window change Build for target:

[image]

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59094823/)