# "Named colors do not work prior to iOS 11.0." even though deployment target is >= iOS 11.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I keep getting Xcode compiler errors "Named colors do not work prior to iOS 11.0." even though the deployment target in Xcode to be iOS 11.0

I've tried changing the deployment target to be 12.2 and cleaning the build folder but the error still persists.

My project settings for deployment are:

```
Targeted Device Family: iPhone

Debug: iPhone

Release: iPhone

iOS Deployment Target: iOS 11.0

Debug: iOS 11.0

Release: iOS 11.0
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open your storyboard, Open 'File inspector' on right panel and change the property 'Builds for' to correct version, maybe 'iOS 11 and Later'

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, the storyboard thought the deployment target was 10.2

I've been racking my brain over this for days. Thanks for teaching me something new!

Answer (score -2):

That's what I did for my app to support iOS 13 dark mode and devices running ios < 11.0. Let say you have a color in assets with dark and light mode and it's called "White"

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    YOUR_OBJECT.backgroundColor = UIColor(name: "White")

}else{
    YOUR_OBJECT.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

For devices below IOS 11 it falls on else section and YOUR_OBJECT will be white. For devices running  11<= ios <13, it picks the light mode of UIColor(name: "White"). For devices running ios 13.0, it also picks UIColor(name: "White") but according to light/dark mode version of the color defined in assets